# Formatting Compare-Object Ouput

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Hello all and good morning.

I'm just looking to see if I can format the output of Compare-Object into a pscustomobject.
I have taken a look at the following questions that are similar:

- [PowerShell Compare-Object SideIndicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361968/powershell-compare-object-sideindicator)
- [Compare-Object Format Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712065/compare-object-format-output)
- [Compare-Object Output Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069556/compare-object-output-format)

...but, I just don't seem to grasp the concept of it. I hate to ask questions that are already have been answered that correlate to this but, im just a bit confused. The 3rd link was the only one I was beginning to understand but, still got lost in the sauce.

Just looking to separate the output based off the `SideIndicator` return property.

```
$Reference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj1.txt"
$Difference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj2.txt"


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Reference -DifferenceObject $Difference -IncludeEqual | Tee-Object -Variable CompareObject | Out-Null
$compareObject | Foreach { 
$ONJ1 = $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" | Select $_.InputObject
$ONJ2 = $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" | Select $_.InputObject
$Both = $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" | Select $_.inputobject

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ONJ1 = $ONJ1
        ONJ2 = $ONJ2
        Both = $Both
                }
        }
```

Unfortunately, all 3 columns return the same output and im assuming its because im selecting the InputObject property but, it grabs them all.

EDIT: As explained by Zett42

```
$Reference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj1.txt"
$Difference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj2.txt"


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Reference -DifferenceObject $Difference -IncludeEqual | Tee-Object -Variable CompareObject | Out-Null

$null = [array]$ONJ1 = $compareObject | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
$null = [array]$ONJ2 = $compareObject | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
$null = [array]$Both = $compareObject | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject


For($i=0; $i -lt ($ONJ1.Count + $ONJ2.Count + $Both.Count); $i++){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ONJ1 = $ONJ1[$i]
        ONJ2 = $ONJ2[$i]
        Both = $Both[$i]
                }
        }
```

Comment: Great that you reference the questions you've already explored, but you seem to have forgotten to describe what you're hoping to accomplish :-) What is it you're hoping to see on screen, and what will you be using the resulting object for?

Comment: Sorry! Thought I included it. Its not really being used for something specific, just  to try and add the names in the text file to the corresponding column assigned to it by the var.

Comment: So you want the output file to contain a formatted table with three variable-length "columns"?

Comment: Well, the contents within the files themselves separated by the difference in sideindicators, but yes. Into its own separate columns based off that. If that makes sense?

Comment: You can remove the `$null =`. Variable assignment doesn't produce output by default (you would have to enclose whole statement into parenthesis to make it produce output, e. g. `($a = 42)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grabbing the formatted output strings, not the actual data from `Compare-Object`. The formatted output will be hard to process, because it is just unstructured strings. Store direct output of `Compare-Object` into a variable, without piping to other cmdlets. Then you do further processing based on that data.

```
$reference = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bim'
$difference = 'bim', 'fop', 'bar'

$compareObject = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Reference -DifferenceObject $Difference -IncludeEqual
```

Then separate the result based on the `SideIndicator`:

```
[array] $left  = $compareObject | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' | 
                                  Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
[array] $right = $compareObject | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' | 
                                  Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
[array] $both  = $compareObject | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '==' |
                                  Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

The variable `$left` is an array that contains only items that are in `$Reference`, `$right` contains only items that are in `$Difference` and `$both` obviously contains items that are in both `$Reference` and `$Difference`.

<sub>NOTE: I've explicitly set the type of the variables to `[array]` so we can treat single element output the same as multiple elements. Applying the index operator to a single string would select a single *character*, whereas applying the index operator to an *array* of strings would output a single *string*. By explicitly setting the variable type to `[array]` we handle both cases without extra code.</sub>

Now we can do further processing based on the separated results, e. g. stuffing them into a single array of `[PSCustomObject]`:

```
# Determine the total number of rows we need. -1 to make it a valid array index.
$maxIndex = ( $left.Count, $right.Count, $both.Count | Measure-Object -Maximum ).Maximum - 1

foreach( $i in 0..$maxIndex ) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ONJ1 = if( $i -lt $left.Count )  { $left[ $i ] }  else { $null }
        ONJ2 = if( $i -lt $right.Count ) { $right[ $i ] } else { $null }
        Both = if( $i -lt $both.Count )  { $both[ $i ] }  else { $null }
    }
}
```

The `if`/`else` on the right-hand side of an assignment is called [conditional assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31341998/7571258) (aka ternary operator). As each of the arrays `$left`, `$right` and `$both` may have different size (less than `$maxIndex`), we need to make sure to not "overshoot" and use an invalid index.

Actually this is only necessary when using strict mode >= v3.0 (e. g. `Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0`), in which case you would get a fatal "index out of bounds" error when specifying an invalid array index. Without strict mode, you could write `ONJ1 = $left[ $i ]` without checking the index. Personally I prefer to know that my indices are always correct and not rely on the programming language to silently "fix" my errors.

**Output:**

```text
ONJ1 ONJ2 Both
---- ---- ----
foo  fop  bar
baz       bim
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It all makes sense to me now, see updated question for the code I did to complete it. Thank you!

Comment: its so odd as i used the same method to index but, it spread one of the difference names into a new row until the name finished. Guess its because it wasn't listed as an array to begin with? Though it was read as such when specified through the `Get-Content` and stored in the variable `ONJ2`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala If you don't explicitly set the type of the variable to `[array]` (or use the array literal operator `@()`) it may be a single object instead. In case of a string you would then index into the individual characters. I've modified the code to use `[array]` instead of `@()`. It's a matter of preference, personally I think `[array]` is clearer. I don't like parenthesis. ;-)

Comment: you and I both!

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you expect as formatted output, but perhaps something ;ike this?

**onj1.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor.
```

**onj2.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
sed do eiusmod tempor.
```

```
$Reference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj1.txt"
$Difference = Get-Content "C:\Users\Abe\Desktop\onj2.txt"

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Reference -DifferenceObject $Difference -IncludeEqual

[PsCustomObject]@{
    ONJ1 = ($compare | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).InputObject -join [environment]::NewLine
    ONJ2 = ($compare | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"}).InputObject -join [environment]::NewLine
    Both = ($compare | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}).InputObject -join [environment]::NewLine
} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Output:

```
ONJ1                                                      ONJ2                         Both                  
----                                                      ----                         ----                  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  sed do eiusmod tempor.
consectetur adipiscing elit,
```